# Bootstrap card columns change images size

Tags: theme-development, gallery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrao masonry grid made using the card columns technique. The images that will be part of the grid are all of the same size and this will not give the desired masonry like effect when the wordpress loop is loading the content. I was trying to use the PHP `array_chunk()` to split the post gallery that I'm using to make the grid, but the result isn't what I was expecting. Is it possible to apply a different class or height to the images every 2 or 3 images?